# How to access developer tools (network log) from my extension

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, opera, browser-extension, browser-addons

I'm writing an extension in Google chrome and Opera

I need to watch for specific URLs loaded, when i type one url in the address bar.
example:
if i goto www.google.com, it will load couple of other urls / images, etc.. those will be shown in Developer tools->Network.

Is there anyway, i can access that log from my extension background page?

Please let me know

Comment: I found that in google chrome, There is Experimental API for this,that works great, but not sure about the Opera

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you can listen for load events that will fire on the images inside the page:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(e){ /* e.target is a newly loaded image */ }, true)
```

Whether this solves your problem depends on what your use case is exactly..